# How to get device token for push notification purpose in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to get device token which I can use as Token for push notification.

I have ready many blogs but didn't find device token. I also need to pass this in Token input to send notification in UrbanAirship.

Example: 555D111CC00D77FA2956E85648D3B4187B42AF737BBB1670FE6EF8595784DR654

Please suggest

Comment: What do you plan on using for push notification service?

Comment: @G.hakim To sending any notification to app users. I want to use UrbanAirship that is for sure. Please guide

Comment: check this? :https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/xamarin/

Answer (score 5):

Please refer this for detailed information https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification

You can use CrossPushNotification Plugin for xamarin.Forms

1. Implement IPushNotificationListener
2. iOS:
   In AppDelegate

   ```
   public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
   {
    //Consider inizializing before application initialization, if using any 
      CrossPushNotification method during application initialization.
      CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener> ();
    //...
    return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
   }
   ```
3. Android: In MainActivity

   ```
   public override void OnCreate()
   {
     base.OnCreate();

    //...

    //Should specify android Sender Id as parameter 
     CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>(" 
     <ANDROID SENDER ID>");            
    //...
    }
   ```

And on your App.cs you need to add

```
protected override void OnStart()
    {
        CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();
    }
```